# Grails - issue dependencies

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm using in my project spring security and searchable plugins. Since my migration to a new machine and STS version I have many issues when I try to compile my project.

....

> == resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#myProject;0.1->org.grails.plugins#spring-security-ldap;1.0.6
>   [runtime->default] cache: Checking cache for: dependency:
>   org.grails.plugins#spring-security-ldap;1.0.6 {runtime=[default]}
>         tried C:\MyWorkSpace\myProject/lib/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6.zip
>         tried
>   C:\Users\xxxxxx.grails\2.0.3\projects\myProject\plugins\hibernate-2.0.3/lib/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6.zip
>   ... ERROR: Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/security/spring-security-ldap/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-ldap-3.2.0.RC1.jar
>     http://repo.spring.io/milestone: no ivy file nor artifact found for
>   org.springframework.security#spring-security-ldap;3.2.0.RC1 ...

I cannot dowloading trough the proxy/firewall so I downloaded the differents zip from http://grails.org/plugin

In **BuildConfig.groovy** I added this:

```
grails.plugin.location."searchable-0.6.4" = "C:/grails-searchable-0.6.4"
grails.plugin.location."spring-security-core-1.x" = "C:/grails-spring-security-core-1.x"
grails.plugin.location."spring-security-ldap-master" = "C:/grails-spring-security-ldap-master"
```

I tried to perform a clean, delete ivy cache but nothing change

Comment: plugins have dependencies, you need to solve you problem with proxy :)